# Bind onlick events on several links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently working on a solution for an application that is written in PHP, but needs a JS solution for a preview link and I am stuck with binding onclick-events on the links. The HTML is given and may not be changed. (so no adding of classes and stuff, even though that would be easier)

My initial thought was to just get each of the *li* and perform a callable that sets the event and defines the rules for what happens, when the link is clicked.

I am unsure what is the best possible solution to get the values of the two Inputs, belonging to the preview link, as while I was running the code mentioned above on what ever link I clicked, the last item was logged.

So basically this is 2 questions in one:
1. how to properly bind the click events.
2. how to best acces the inputs belonging to the link

```js
var items = $('div.foobar').find('li');
items.each(function() {
  this = $(this);

  url = lo_this.find('a').attr('href');
  this.find('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this)


    /** here is the point, where I got stuck **/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foobar">
  <li>
    <a href="somelinkwithID">Link</a>
    <div class="justaname">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[ID][foo]" value="">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[ID][bar]" maxlength="50" value="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="somelinkwithOTHERID">Link</a>
    <div class="justaname">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[OTHERID][foo]" value="">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[OTHERID][bar]" maxlength="50" value="">
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to close your links

Comment: `this = $(this);` should be `const lo_this = $(this);` I guess. Use `let` instead of var to find the link and inputs. That way you can refer to the inputs in the click handler. Another way is to go up the tree from the link using `closest('li')`, the back down to the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

1. Assuming your inputs are in the same LI as the anchor
2. Ignoring the ID of the anchor and just getting the inputs in the same LI

Other code is needed if you want to use the ID of the link to access the named links

```js
$('div.foobar li a').on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("li").find("input").each(function() {
     console.log(this.name,this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foobar">
  <li>
    <a href="somelinkwithID">Link</a>
    <div class="justaname">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[ID][foo]" value="">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[ID][bar]" maxlength="50" value="">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="somelinkwithOTHERID">Link</a>
    <div class="justaname">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[OTHERID][foo]" value="">
      <input type="text" name="somenamewith[OTHERID][bar]" maxlength="50" value="">
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd use 100% jQuery, i.e. replace `e.preventDefault();` with `return false;`

Comment: @ChrisG [`event.preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is part of jQuery too, and different to `return false`. [The event handler and its environment](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler): `[…]Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()[…]`

Comment: I prefer e.preventDefault BECAUSE: the link will not execute EVEN if something on the way to the return false gives error. Any error between function() { and return false that fails, will allow the click

Comment: That's true, please ignore :)

Comment: the assumtion is correct and is acceptable for me, as the html is not subjecto to change in the future, therefor this is an easy way. I really appreciat your input and the fast answer @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to bind click events to your links and then do whatever with the input elements contained by the div after the clicked link:

```
$('.foobar li a').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().find('input').each(function(){
    //Whatever you want to do for each input
  });
});
```

Comment: [.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) does not find a collection - see my solution to get both inputs